# Bash shopt xpg_echo

Tags: bash, echo, shopt

I don't understand what the shopt `xpg_echo` changes if it is activated or deactivated.

In the manual:

```
xpg_echo
         If  set,  the  echo  builtin  expands   backslash-escape
         sequences by default.
```

I tried to activate/deactivate xpg_echo, but echo has the same behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

It determines if echo will process escape-sequences like `\n`:

```
$ shopt -u xpg_echo # Disable xpg_echo
$ echo "Hello\nworld"
Hello\nworld
$ shopt -s xpg_echo # Enable xpg_echo
$ echo "Hello\nworld"
Hello
world
```

Comment: This is only half of the behavior; with the `posix` flag set at the same time, it also makes bash comply with the letter of the standard for `echo`, and thus print `-e` on output when `echo -e` is run. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html (being sure not to overlook the APPLICATION USAGE section).